# Copy and paste format including colour of cells VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

```
wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:W79").Value = wb.Sheets(wsSource.Name).Range("A1:W79").Value
```

I have this code which works pasting the values of wb.Sheets(wsSource.Name) to wbTarget sheets. However, it only pastes the value and not the format/color. How do I paste it including the fonts, color of cell.

Comment: Perhaps you could do what you want manually with the macro recorder turned on, and then look at the resulting code.

Comment: Do you want the equivalent of `Ctrl-C` - `Ctrl-V` - i.e. a full copy, or *just* the value, font and colour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `Copy`, and `PasteSpecial xlValues` and `PasteSpecial xlFormats`.

```
' Copy
wb.Sheets(wsSource.Name).Range("A1:W79").Copy
' Paste Special
wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:W79").PasteSpecial xlValues
wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:W79").PasteSpecial xlFormats
```

Read about `Range.PasteSpecial` here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! Can I change the Range to be dynamic? So I hope to copy everything dynamically and not just A1:W79. How should I substitute it?

Comment: @Desmond what is changing ? number of rows ? columns ? both ?

Comment: Both can change. So if the sheet contains data in A1:W79, I would copy and paste that. If a sheet contains data in C3:F7, I would copy that.