# VBA code for cell formating linked to another sheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) Me.sheets("WAM Data").Range("BY5:HW35").Interior.Color = Me.sheets("WAM  
Exception").Range("BO7:HM37").Interior.Color
End Sub
```

But its giving error in code.

What I want to do is, change the cell formatting (color) of `"BY5 to HW35"` as `"BO7:HM37"`.
If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy and paste format including colour of cells VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112386/copy-and-paste-format-including-colour-of-cells-vba-excel)

Comment: Well yeah that is much simpler way, Thanks.. Now it saved me from trying to stop the macro to run continuously.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete `me.` and use only `Sheets...`, or use `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets..` to refer to the activeworkbook, or `ThisWorkbook.Sheets...` to refer to the workbook the macro is run from, or `Workbooks("name").Sheets...` to choose whichever workbook you want from the ones you have open.

However, your macro will just run on first click of a mouse, regardless where that happens on your spreadsheet, with no conditions add to it... is that what you want to do with your code?

Comment: Actually I could come up with this only, yes I know it will then be continuous code and it keeps running every time, which is making my sheet slower. Do you have any suggestion what I can do to make it better so that I changes the color in "WAM data" sheet when it changes in "WAM exception" sheet?