# How can I copy the formatting of a row from an Excel spreadsheet and paste it into another Excel spreadsheet using MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an input spreadsheet and an output spreadsheet that's generated after calculations are run through MATLAB. I need the formatting of the output spreadsheet's header row to match the input spreadsheet's header row (mainly the column width).
Can anyone please help with the MATLAB code for this? Perhaps if there's a way to utilize the format-copy and paste functions in Excel but coded into MATLAB?

I've been working on this for weeks and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I have as of right now:

```
    sheetIndex = 1;
    ExcelWorkbook.Sheets.Item( 'Input.xlsx' ).Activate;
    sourceCellRange = 'A3..Z3';
    Excel.Range(sourceCellRange).Copy;

    sheetIndex = 2;
    ExcelWorkbook.Sheets.Item( 'Output.xlsm' ).Activate;
    destinationCellRange = 'A3..Z3'; 
    Excel.Range(destinationCellRange).Select;
    Excel.ActiveSheet.Paste;
    Excel.Range('A1').Select;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I added some details and the code I have so far to my question.

Comment: Did you try to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112386/copy-and-paste-format-including-colour-of-cells-vba-excel)?

Comment: I have tried to adapt that solution, yes. It sadly didn't work for me though.