# How to insert table in Word without clipboard using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

Currently I'm working on improving a translated Word VBA code in VB.net. The program processes 200+ Word documents. So far, the program is running OK. I have an issue with inserting a table that contains images and text (from a template, `wTemp`) at the begining of each of the documents (`wDoc`). The way it is done now (and in the VBA) uses the clipboard - copy wTemp.Table(1) and paste it at `wDoc.range(0,0)`.

However, there are at least two issues with this:

- `wTemp` needs to be open all the time (not a major issue)
- since the process of converting 200+ files takes some time, the user might want to proceed with other activites, and copy/paste approach may interfere with his work!

What I would like to achieve is described in the following (pseudo) code:

```vb
open wTemp(readonly)
dim wTable as word.table = wTemp.tables(1) ' the table I need is the first one
close wTemp(false) ' preferably!
for each wDoc in someCollection
  open wDoc
  wDoc.Application.Selection.HomeKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove)
  ' here comes the copy/paste code that works, but I want to replace it with something like this
   ' insert wTable at current selection point
   wDoc.Range.FormattedText = wTable.Range.FormattedText 'thanks to @Oscar-sun

  wDoc.save
  wDoc.close(false)
next wDoc
wTemp.close(false) ' if I have to keep it open for the duration of the loop
```

I understand that `tables.add()` method allows you to inserts a table with rows/colums, but I don't need to construct the table since it is already in wTemp.

**UPDATE**

I completely overlooked the `.Range.FormattedText` property! Thanks to [@Oscar-Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8249058/oscar-sun) I updated the code with the missing statement:

`wDoc.Range.FormattedText = wTable.Range.FormattedText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.formattedtext?view=word-pia) [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.formattedtext) instead of the clipboard method, refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76781627/8249058):

```vb
Rem implement without the clipboard
myDoc.Range(tbl.Cell(tbl.Rows.count, 1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(tbl.Rows.count, 1).Range.Start).FormattedText = tbl.Rows(2).Range.FormattedText
```

So, TRY THIS FIRST! give it a shot !!

```vb
open wTemp(readonly)
dim wTable as word.table = wTemp.tables(1) ' the table I need is the first one
close wTemp(false) ' preferably!
for each wDoc in someCollection
  open wDoc
  wDoc.Application.Selection.HomeKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove)
  ' here comes the copy/paste code that works, but I want to replace it with something like this

      'insert wTable at current selection point
        Selection.Range.FormattedText= wTable.Range.FormattedText'TRY THIS FIRST ! give it a shot !!
        rem And remember ： Try to avoid using Selection objects, but use Range objects. OK?
        
        
  wDoc.save
  wDoc.close(false)
next wDoc
wTemp.close(false) ' if I have to keep it open for the duration of the loop
```

Comment: Thanks @Oscar. I've updated my question with your answer