# copy from worksheet and paste to email body with formatting

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to get a better copy/paste method.
Generally I use Ron de Bruin's code (https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail4.htm).

But from my worksheet I am copying a pivot table and I'd like to paste it into email body with all formats, including shading and borders, as you usually do with ctrl+C -> ctrl+V.

So when copying manually, either to other excel sheet, or to outlook email body, all formatting is kept.
When I use the below code, shading and borders are lost.

May I ask for a hint on how to keep all of it?

There is no point of me quoting here all Ron's code, I will just paste only this part of code which is responsible for pasting into email:

```
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Comment: Here about pasting the formatting https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112452/18247317

Comment: @OranG.Utan it doesn't work. I have a suspicion that shading and borders are not part of the copy in Ron's code. Is it even possible?